# How to download the latest file from a GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github

I'm very new to GitHub. I am trying to download `JSON` files from a repository on GitHub. Every day, a new `.json` file is released. Is there a way in Python/Git to find this latest file uploaded from the folder full of `JSON` files and download it. I don't want to clone the entire folder every day.

Comment: Wouldn’t you pull changes on your existing copy every day after cloning it once?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. If that's true, that's just what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways; some are specific to GitHub.  In particular GitHub provide a web service endpoint to download one particular file from one particular commit, and you can refer to the commit via branch name (so that GitHub will resolve the commit hash ID for you):

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/checkout.c
```

for instance gets you `checkout.c` out of whatever commit `master` identifies at the moment in the Git repository at `github.com/git/git`.

If you're concerned about cloning, though:

> I don't want to clone the entire folder every day.

First, you don't clone a *folder*.  You clone a *repository*.  Once you have done so, you have *all* the commits for *all* the files, and the next day, you can just run `git fetch` in this repository, which obtains *new* commits while retaining all the existing commits.  Git is very efficient at these updates.  Depending on the JSON file involved, and other repository activity, this may be *faster* than downloading one raw file.

If the repository is purely read-only, and the upstream is well-behaved, you can run `git pull` instead of `git fetch` followed by a second Git command.  The second Git command would be `git merge`, and `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command* and the second command defaults to `git merge`.  The merge step in this case will be a *fast-forward* operation.

(If the upstream repository is *not* well behaved, your second command will be `git reset --hard origin/master` and you'll need two commands.)